# Who are the masked attackers in Saw 3D?

Tags: character, saw, saw-3d

**SPOILER HEREIN**

At the end of *[Saw 3D](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1477076/)*, we see Hoffman finally get his comeuppance at the hands of Dr. Gordon, the original victim.

However, when Hoffman is attacked and subdued in the parking lot, there are two additional assailants wearing pig masks along with Gordon - I assumed these were other 'survivors' possibly from the earlier meeting, but is there any official explanation as to their identity?

Hired thugs?

Did I miss something?

Comment: You didn't missed anything. The two other maskman never got revealed. They can be hired hit-man. John has also used hired person in the series in some points.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Saw_characters#Brad.2C_Dina.2C_and_Ryan):-

> According to the producers commentary Brad and Ryan are the two men in
>   the pig masks that help Lawrence Gordon abduct Hoffman.

Answer (score 3):

> After destroying his workshop, Hoffman is captured by three pig-masked figures, led by Lawrence Gordon. Flashbacks reveal that John Kramer found Lawrence by the steam pipe and helped him recover, and Lawrence had helped John in secret ever since. Tasked with watching over Jill and taking action of anything happened to her, Lawrence brings Hoffman to the underground bathroom and shackles him by the ankle. [from Saw 3D wiki](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Saw_3D)

There is no evidence, hint or any clue to guess who the masked figures could be. Speculation suggests they could be past victims of Jigsaw, or entirely new characters recruited by Gordon. Personally, I'm more inclined to believe they are the past victims that just took away Hoffman because of Jill.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been Daniel Erick's son but not one hundred percent sure. Then there are other possibilities. Simone Bethson  who had to chop her arms off or Addy from Saw 6,  Malik and Brit from Saw 5, or Brad and Ryan from Saw 3D. These are just possibilities but not absolute.

Answer (score -1):

What about Eleanor and Logan from Jigsaw, not sure but one of the two pig-masked looked like a girl on the left. Not only that but it is Logan who became John's first true helper because he helped make Amanda's jaw trap, which happened before Gordon's trap. John let Logan survive because Logan was overdosed or didn't wake up until he was near the saws.

Answer (score -2):

One of the men is Daniel Erick's son, because he was not killed - he was the one feeding his dad and taking care of him. The second was Riggs: you never saw him die or anything; Dr Gordan could have easily fixed his wound. It's obvious that the two masked men are Daniel Mathews and Detective Riggs.

Comment: it will be better if you add some citation or link or text backing your answer

Comment: Any single proof for the claim?

Comment: Officer Rigg was shot in the head or chest by Art Blank. He bleeds to death on the floor it says on "wiki" @Randal'Thor